# Take a snapshot of video in mediaelement without violating MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mediaelement

I need to take a snapshot of video playing in MediaElement.

Below link explains how we can achieve this.

http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/04/06/take-snapshots-of-videos-with-wpf/

But how  to do it without violating MVVM pattern.

Comment: You might want to summarise that link into your question a bit more for future readers in the event the link breaks

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button Command="{Binding TakeSnapshotCommand}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=media}"/>
```

Where TakeSnapshotCommand is a class implementing ICommand like [RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030). Additionaly you send parameter T, in this case T is MediaElement so you will have following declaration.

```
private RelayCommand<MediaElement> _takeSnapshotCommand;
public RelayCommand<MediaElement> TakeSnapshotCommand
{
get{ return _takeSnapshotCommand ??(_takeSnapshotCommand = new RelayCommand<MediaElement>(YourMethodTakingMediaElementAsParameter));}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to pass mediaelement to viewmodel. I think in MVVM pattern it's not advisable to operate on UI components in viewmodel. Is there any way so that I can pass only bitmap image of video snapshot as command parameter.

Comment: You can pass whatever you want. Use Converter in CommandParameter to adjust retrieving value.

Comment: As it stands, not really MVVM.  A binding converter that converts the element into an image, yeah, that would be a decent design.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the code in the link doesn't violate the MVVM pattern... It uses code-behind, which is not advised in MVVM, but it is not a violation.

That being said, that code would be better in a reusable UserControl or custom Control, returning the snapshot through an Event, Command or DependencyProperty so you can then bind it to your ViewModel.

But that's more a matter of good practice, in general, and not an MVVM requirement.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SnapShots.SnapShotMediaViewer"
    xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/...
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="MediaViewer">
  <StackPanel>
   <MediaElement x:Name="media" Stretch="Fill" Height="200" Width="300">
      <MediaElement.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
          <MediaTimeline Source="thomasOnBoard.wmv"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
         </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
       </EventTrigger>
      </MediaElement.Triggers>
     </MediaElement>
     <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Snapshot"/>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And in code-behind, expose the snapshot through an Event, for instance. Or if you want to completely avoid code-behind or EventTriggers in your view, use a DependencyProperty.

```
public partial class SnapShotMediaViewer : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey SnapshotPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Snapshot", typeof(BitmapSource),
            typeof(SnapShotMediaViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SnapshotProperty =
        SnapshotPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public BitmapSource Snapshot
    {
        get 
        {
            return (BitmapSource)GetValue(SnapshotProperty); 
        }
        private set
        {
            SetValue(SnapshotProperty, value);
        }
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Size dpi = new Size(96,96);
        RenderTargetBitmap bmp = 
            new RenderTargetBitmap(300, 200, 
            dpi.Width, dpi.Height, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(media);

        Snapshot = bmp;
    }
}
```

Then simply add this control to your view and create a Binding to the `Snapshot` property.